# close pagerenderer created in ios project using xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have created a PageRenderer of a page using following steps:

1. I have created a page in PCL project with nothing declared in it.
2. Created a PageRenderer and declared elements as per my need. I used await Navigation.PushAsync (new MyPage (), true); to open it.
3. After desired operation completes, I want to close this page and go back to previous page.

Please suggest how i can do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include a code example so we can better answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

to navigate away from a page, use `Navigation.PopAsync()`

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere after your `PushAsync` returns, you will call `PopAsync` to remove the page

[Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage Class](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage/)

---

```
var newPage = new ContentPage ();
await Navigation.PushAsync (newPage);
Debug.WriteLine ("the new page is now showing");
var poppedPage = await Navigation.PopAsync ();
Debug.WriteLine ("the new page is dismissed");
```